# Angular 5 - How to set via CLI a CSS preprocessor for already existing projects

Tags: angular, angular-cli

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44676462/4314952) there is the possiblity to choose a preprocessor for .css files while initializing a new Angular project via CLI.

`ng new my-first-app --style less`

Ist there a possiblity to set an preprocessor via CLI for an already existing project?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-css-preprocessors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you please try the following command:

ng set defaults.styleExt less